# Erro ao fazer upload de arquivos no Ubuntu com PHP

Tags: php

Olá, estou utilizando um sistema simples de upload de arquivos com PHP e alguns problemas surgirão em relação as permissões necessárias a utilizar no ubuntu

É a primeira vez que estou utilizando o mesmo, com a ferramente Webmin e não sei quais permissões utilizar, e muito menos como dar elas.

Meu código de upload:

```
if ( isset( $_FILES[ 'anexo' ][ 'name' ] ) && $_FILES[ 'anexo' ][ 'error' ] == 0 ) {

// Pasta onde o arquivo vai ser salvo
$_UP['pasta'] = '/../../arquivos_subidos/'; 
// Tamanho máximo do arquivo (em Bytes)
$_UP['tamanho'] = 1024 * 1024 * 2; // 2Mb
// Array com as extensões permitidas
$_UP['extensoes'] = array('docx', 'pdf', 'xls', 'xlsx');
// Renomeia o arquivo? (Se true, o arquivo será salvo como (nome unico + .docx)
$_UP['renomeia'] = true;
// Array com os tipos de erros de upload do PHP
$_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
$_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite do PHP';
$_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho especifiado no HTML';
$_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
$_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo';
// Verifica se houve algum erro com o upload. Se sim, exibe a mensagem do erro
if ($_FILES['anexo']['error'] != 0) {
  return $templates->render->erro("Não foi possível fazer o upload, erro:" . $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['anexo']['error']]); // Para a execução do script
}
// Caso script chegue a esse ponto, não houve erro com o upload e o PHP pode continuar
// Faz a verificação da extensão do arquivo
$separaExtensao = explode('.', $_FILES['anexo']['name']);
$pegaUltimaExtensao = end($separaExtensao);
$extensao = strtolower($pegaUltimaExtensao);

if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes']) === false) 
   return $templates->render->erro("Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: docx, pdf ou xls");    

// Faz a verificação do tamanho do arquivo
if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['anexo']['size']) 
    return $templates->render->erro("O arquivo enviado é muito grande, envie arquivos de até 2Mb.");

// O arquivo passou em todas as verificações, hora de tentar movê-lo para a pasta
// Primeiro verifica se deve trocar o nome do arquivo
if ($_UP['renomeia'] == true) {
  // Cria um nome baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual 
  $nome_final = md5(time()."$@(DU@$#%%").".".$extensao;
} else {
  // Mantém o nome original do arquivo
  $nome_final = $_FILES['anexo']['name'];
}

// Depois verifica se é possível mover o arquivo para a pasta escolhida
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['anexo']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final)) {
  return $templates->render->sucesso("O arquivo foi enviado com sucesso.");
} else {
  // Não foi possível fazer o upload, provavelmente a pasta está incorreta
    return $templates->render->erro("Não foi possivel fazer o upload do arquivo, tente novamente");

}
```

}

O PHP me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Warning: 
>   move_uploaded_file(/../../arquivos_subidos/13d0bd5da89e48105287dfba2e773163.docx):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/core/ajax/novaProposta.php on line 81
>
> Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpljFq6X' to
>   '/../../arquivos_subidos/13d0bd5da89e48105287dfba2e773163.docx' in
>   /var/www/html/core/ajax/novaProposta.php on line 81

Minha ideia: os arquivos subidos não ficam onde o php é executado, dentro da pasta /var/www eu criei uma chamada "arquivos_subidos", mas não sei configurara s permissões necessarias para que o upload seja feito com sucesso.

No ambiente Windows este script funciona corretamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que vi seu problema é com as permissões do sistema de arquivos do linux (coisa que o windows não faz por isso la funciona) se não me engano voce precisa dar permissões nessa pasta para o APACHE escrever então voce pode dar a posse desse diretório para o apache com o comando `sudo chown www-data:www-data caminho/da/pasta` ou dar permissão total na pasta `sudo chmod -R 777 caminho/da/pasta` essa ultima não é muito recomendada pois qualquer usuário poderá alterar o conteúdo dessa pasta. Você deve dar permissão para o apache pois é ele quem executa seu script PHP, portanto é ele quem precisa de permissão de escrita nessa pasta. Espero que tenha ficado claro.

Comment: Bom dia, obrigado! executei o comando e o upload foi feito com sucesso